# What can somebody do with a Facebook access_token?

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-access-token

Say you have a Facebook app which uses an external API to fetch relevant data for the user using this app. The API needs the user's `access_token` to retrieve this relevant data. Since the API is a separate service, it needs to be provided with a Facebook `access_token` to retrieve the relevant data (it cannot get the `access_token` of the logged in user because it runs on a separate domain than the one the user is logged into).

One way of giving the `access_token` to the API is by making an HTTP request (sync or async, doesn't matter).

The question is, what can somebody do if it intercepts this `access_token` (because, obviously, it can be intercepted in an HTTP request)? Is it somehow protected by unauthorized use or it can be used by anyone to query the Facebook API on whatever that individual wants?

Comment: It can be used to query and create everything that’s within the permissions scope of the token. You should think about using HTTPS for transferring the token, that will reduce the risk of it being stolen on the way massively. (Since you only need your two servers to communicate with each other, you can use a self-signed certificate for this.)

Comment: And is there some other method to make the access_token accessible in the API besides passing it in a request?